# How to store null bytes into memory address with strcpy

Tags: c, shell, security, command-line

For a security course in university I need to execute a shell via a data only vulnerability.

The c code contains a **strcpy()** statement, so I can overwrite a struct with the memory address of a certain buffer. Let's say this buffer is allocated at `0xbfffecfc`

I need to enter the value 1 (`0x00000001`) at this buffer address via the command line. This happens via the **strcpy()** function which writes directly to `0xbfffecfc`

I already tried
`python -c 'print "\x01\x00\x00\x00"`
But this does not work, because the `\x00` byte terminates the input.

How can I get this value of one into the buffer?

Comment: You can't use `strcpy`, it's for NUL terminated strings. You probably need `memcpy` although I'm not quite sure what you're asking; maybe you should show the piece of code you mentioned.

Comment: No, `strcpy()` will never ever ever write more than one single byte with value `0`. Never.

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but is there maybe another method to get 0x00000001 in that memory address via strcpy()? Maybe a another value than \x00 to add, which does not change the value of 1 into the address?

Comment: You can't do it with a single call to `strcpy()`, but you can do several calls, each time writing part of the final buffer.

Comment: `strcpy(0xbfffecfc, ""); strcpy(0xbfffecfd, ""); strcpy(0xbfffecfe, ""); strcpy(0xbfffecff, "");`

Comment: Maybe I should redefine the question and ask: How can I store the decimal value 1 into a hexadeximal memory address. The ony thing to use is one strcpy() that directly copies the value to `0xbfffecfd`

Comment: Re “The [only] thing to use is one strcpy() that directly copies the value”: This is impossible with a little-endian byte order and four-byte `int`; `strcpy` will not do that job regardless of what arguments it is passed.

Comment: I need to transport 4 people from the airport to the city center ... but I have only a motorbiike and can only do one trip, cannot use a car, or a truck or a plane, or a train, ... just the bike, once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strcpy` is for copying strings, which are sequences of characters whose end is marked with a null character. Therefore, it cannot copy beyond the first null character.

`memcpy` is for copying sequences of bytes of arbitrary length.

To copy `"\0x01\0x00\0x00\0x00"`, which represents a four-byte 1 with little-endian byte order, use `memcpy(destination, "\0x01\0x00\0x00\0x00", 4);`.

To copy an `int` with value 1 in the native representation, use `memcpy(destination, (int []) { 1 }, sizeof 1);`.

Comment: Premature (and unnecessary (and pedantic)) optimization: save 1 byte with `memcpy(destination, "\0x01\0x00\0x00", 4);`

Comment: @pmg: Hmm, true, but I wonder how many people it would give pause to in spite of being correct.